# Hover edit icon on span (when its content is longer than span)

Tags: html, css

I try to view show modal window. This window contain multiple span. But there are limited by width and height. And when span content is smaller, than span width: all is OK, I can see this icon.

But when text is to big I could not see this icon. And I didn't have any ideas, how to do this on pure CSS without using Javascript (jQuery).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="first">First</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="second">Second contain a lot of text. Really long span is here</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 236px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 0 16px 0 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fc0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

span:hover{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover::after{
    font: normal normal normal 12px FontAwesome;
    line-height: 30px;
    content: "\f040";
    float: right;
}
```

**First screen, first span: it's OK**

[image]

**Second screen, second span: it's not normal**

[image]

**Third screen, second span: so must be**

[image]

Have any ideas? Also padding, margin must be "user-friendly" and the same in both cases.

**Try it here:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpMdvx

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/oXLjox

Comment: @0_o tnx, i know with absolute... but want to know without it, in my case it is important...

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 236px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fc0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
span:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span:hover::before {
  font: normal normal normal 12px FontAwesome;
  line-height: 30px;
  content: "\f040";
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="first">First</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="second">Second contain a lot of text. Really long span is here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It works even without `text-overflow: ellipsis` on `::before`.

Comment: yeah i noticed, I was trying out a few things. `position:relative` on wrapper and changing `:after` to `:before` will get the desired result.

Comment: You don't need `position: relative` on `wrapper`, only change `::after` to `::before`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your text has a `whitespace: nowrap;` setting and is reaching the end of the box, this won't work without using `position: absolute;` on the icon. Just give the span `position: relative;` and apply an extra right-padding on hover.